# How to get members in a local windows group using LDAP and c++

Tags: c++, ldap

I’m trying to retrieve a list of members in a local group in windows. I know how it is done using directory search when connecting to *ldap://rootdse*. But those are domain groups. I don’t know how to get a directory search interface while trying to retrieve the users on a **local** group.

This is the code I'm using to retrieve group members from the LDAP Server:

```
HRESULT performSearch(BAB::WString& query, LPWSTR* columns, DWORD colCnt, searchResults& results)
{
  HRESULT hr = S_OK;

  if (!m_pSearch)
    return E_POINTER;

  DWORD dwLength = MAX_PATH * 2;

  //  Specify subtree search.
  ADS_SEARCHPREF_INFO SearchPrefs;
  SearchPrefs.dwSearchPref = ADS_SEARCHPREF_SEARCH_SCOPE;
  SearchPrefs.vValue.dwType = ADSTYPE_INTEGER;
  SearchPrefs.vValue.Integer = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE;
  DWORD dwNumPrefs = 1;

  //  Set search preference.
  hr = m_pSearch->SetSearchPreference(&SearchPrefs, dwNumPrefs);
  if (FAILED(hr))
    return hr;

  ADS_SEARCH_HANDLE hSearch = NULL;
  if (SUCCEEDED(hr = m_pSearch->ExecuteSearch((LPWSTR)query.c_str(), columns, colCnt, &hSearch)))
  {
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr = m_pSearch->GetFirstRow(hSearch)))
    {
      while (hr != S_ADS_NOMORE_ROWS)
      {
        searchVals val;
        LPWSTR pszColumnName;
        while (m_pSearch->GetNextColumnName(hSearch, &pszColumnName) != S_ADS_NOMORE_COLUMNS)
        {
          ADS_SEARCH_COLUMN col;
          if (SUCCEEDED(hr = m_pSearch->GetColumn(hSearch, pszColumnName, &col)))
          {
            val[pszColumnName] = getColVal(col);
            m_pSearch->FreeColumn(&col);
          }
          FreeADsMem(pszColumnName);
        }
        results.push_back(val);
        hr = m_pSearch->GetNextRow(hSearch);
      }
    }
  }

  return hr;
}

IADs* pObject = NULL;
VARIANT var;
VariantInit(&var);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr = ADsOpenObject(L"LDAP://rootDSE", NULL, NULL, ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION, IID_IADs, (void**)&pObject)))
{
  if (SUCCEEDED(hr = pObject->Get(CComBSTR(L"defaultNamingContext"), &var)))
  {
    BAB::WString wsPath = L"LDAP://";
    wsPath += var.bstrVal;
    hr = ADsOpenObject(wsPath.c_str(), NULL, NULL, ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION, IID_IDirectorySearch, (void**)&m_pSearch);
  }
  VariantClear(&var);
  if (pObject)
    pObject->Release();
}

searchResults results;
BAB::WString query;
query.Format(L"(&(objectCategory=group)(cn=%s))", wszGroup);
LPWSTR groupColumns[] = { (LPWSTR)L"distinguishedName" };
performSearch(query, groupColumns, sizeof(groupColumns) / sizeof(LPWSTR), results);
if (results.size())
{
  LPWSTR userColumns[] = { (LPWSTR)L"sAmAccountName", (LPWSTR)L"objectSid", (LPWSTR)L"objectGUID", (LPWSTR)L"distinguishedName" };
  query.Format(L"(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=%s))", results[0][BAB::WString(L"distinguishedName")].c_str());
  performSearch(query, userColumns, sizeof(userColumns) / sizeof(LPWSTR), members);
}
```

Comment: you cold mention, what you have already tried, where you got stuck. Which ways you have considered. You're probably looking for a command line tool, or are you looking for a say microsoft dll to embed into your program? Your question is kind of unclear to me.

Comment: Im looking for a code that resembles what ive written for ldap server, only on local groups.